# Can the compiler check methods on my .aspx files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

On a C#/asp.net (VS 2008) project I've just changed a signature of a method that is used in a lot of files in the "code in front".

The problem is that the compiler does not add errors to the "Error List" panel with the location of the method calls on the .ascx or .aspx files.

I now have to manually search/check each and every file to see if the method exist in there, which is not the easiest task.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Is this a web site, or a web application project? In either case, the workaround is don't use "code in front".

Comment: Wow... its always strange to see people calmly discussing evil like they were talking about the weather.

Comment: @John, thanks for the comment. I can't, however, control legacy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This article](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/05/compiling-aspx-templates-using.html) should show you how to invoke the ASP.NET compiler from Visual Studio as part of your build process. This will show the errors you want to see at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

Find in Project :)